# Overload division in C#

Tags: c#, overloading

I want to overload division operator in my C# class. So, i wrote:

```
public string[] operator/ (object obj) {

}
```

And got error: "Parser error: Overloadable unary operator excepted".
So, i cant overload that operator?
On the MSDN i don't see any example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx
Thanks.

//i'm using MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 14.10, if it's needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can overload the division operator, but:

- It must always be a binary operator - you've only provider one operand
- It must always be static
- At least one of the operand types must be the type you're declaring it in

So for example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static string operator/ (Program lhs, int rhs)
    {
        return "I'm divided!";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Program() / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, then i have to add second argument to my function? //thanks, your edit answered my question

Comment: Is there a reason why the operator must be static? As opposed to C++ where the other operand is `this`?

Comment: @Borgleader: I guess it just makes it more symmetric for the two cases where the operand is "this type" on the left or right. But either way, there will be two values involved - I don't think it's particularly restrictive.

Comment: Having it as a static also enables you to use operators on things that might be null, which would be hard to do as an instance method.

Comment: @Chris: Well, it would work in an instance method - you might just be a bit surprised that `this` is null. It's observable with a bit of work already, but surprising and non-idiomatic :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hehe yeah that'd suck. Though I think that (at least in C#), you'd get a `NullReferenceException` before getting to that point, so using nulls as operands still wouldn't work!

Comment: @Chris: Not always. As I say, it's possible to observe `this == null`. There's a Stack Overflow question somewhere about it...

Comment: @Chris: Yup, just via `Delegate.CreateDelegate` - create an `Action<Foo>` for a parameterless instance method in `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

The `/` operator is a "binary" operator, meaning that it takes two arguments: `a / b`. The way you've written this, it's trying to overload it as a "unary" operator, such as `a++`.

Something like this ought to work, assuming your class is called "MyObject".

```
public static string[] operator/ (MyObject mine, object obj) {
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
object something = "hi";
string[] result = new MyObject(1) / something;
```