# Parsing and Revising a Math Expression in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, parsing, math

I have a process that creates very long mathematical expressions as a mechanism to run calculations.

However, users now are generating multiple calculation expressions, and are having problems with divide by zero in part of the expression. Sadly, they want to have behavior in these calculations where 3/0 = 0, so it doesn't halt the rest of the calculation. Even though its technically incorrect.

Here's an example of something where they want to see a 1:

```
SELECT (3/0)+1 FROM DUAL
```

I had suggested wrapping divisions in a function, but was told that was too difficult for the users and that should be handled on the backend.

I'm not going to be executing these mathematical expressions right away, I just want to change them.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I see a lot of examples on how to execute dynamic expressions, but not how to revise them.

Ideally, I want to convert any expression like this:

```
SELECT (3/0)+1 FROM DUAL
```

Into

```
SELECT DIVIDE(3,0)+1 FROM DUAL
```

Keeping in mind it might be part of a very complex parse tree, rather than the simple example you see.

I'm not really sure where to start with this one.

The expression will eventually be executed in oracle...i just need to revise the expression...not change the way ill execute it.

Comment: You could always overload the division operator, and change behavior for division by zero (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625627/overload-division-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I found this which may be helpful, I apologize as I have no experience with Oracle, but it looks as if you can create your own custom operator, (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6004.htm#SQLRF01304), then you could do a replace of your division operator with your custom operator in C# before sending to Oracle.

Comment: What are you using now to build the parse tree? How are parse tree nodes represented?  Does the divide operator have its own tree node?  What does a function call to a user defined function look like as a tree? Why can't you replace the divide operator node with a function call node whose arguments are taken from the divide node children?

Comment: Are your users going to make similar request if they write a substring operation with out of bounds indexes?  There's lots of other operators whose operands could cause a runtime exception, where does this slippery slope stop?

Comment: no customized requests concerning substring...no...its just the divide because its a key component of a legacy system...we all love supporting legacy systems...good questions though @IraBaxter

Answer (score 0):

You can use some ANTLR based PL/SQL parser, like [this](https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/blob/master/extlibs/parsing.cpp/OracleDML.g) one. Then construct AST tree, transform it, serialize it, ... etc.

I use similar approach for indentation purposes query rewrite purposes.

But anyway what you're doing is achieve is "hostile" to Oracle, in other words you're trying to "shoot yourself into leg".

Comment: i wouldn't mind doing the revision in c# before it gets sent over

Comment: dont really want to do the parsing the revision in oracle if i can avoid it

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out.  I downloaded and revised the Mathos Math parser.  It will now return strings instead of numbers.

The key part here is the operator.  When it hits the divide, it will return the string I need, instead of a typical "a/b".

```
Operators = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, string>>(7)
            {
                ["^"] = (a, b) => "Power(" + a + "," + b + ")",
                ["%"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "%" + b + ")",
                [":"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "/" + b + ")",
                ["/"] = (a, b) => "(Divide(" + a + "," + b + "))",
                ["*"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "*" + b + ")",
                ["-"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "-" + b + ")",
                ["+"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "+" + b + ")",
            };
```

Here's the full REVISED version of the class

```
/* 
 * Copyright (C) 2012-2018, Mathos Project.
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Please see the license file in the project folder,
 * or go to https://github.com/MathosProject/Mathos-Parser/blob/master/LICENSE.md.
 * 
 * Please feel free to ask me directly at my email!
 *  artem@artemlos.net
 */

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Mathos.Parser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a mathematical expression parser that allows you to perform calculations on string values.
    /// </summary>
    public class MathParserRevised
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// All operators that you want to define should be inside this property.
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, string>> Operators { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// All functions that you want to define should be inside this property.
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, Func<string[], string>> LocalFunctions { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// All variables that you want to define should be inside this property.
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, string> LocalVariables { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// When converting the result from the Parse method or ProgrammaticallyParse method ToString(),
        /// please use this culture info.
        /// </summary>
        public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MathParser class, and optionally with
        /// predefined functions, operators, and variables.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="loadPreDefinedFunctions">This will load abs, cos, cosh, arccos, sin, sinh, arcsin, tan, tanh, arctan, sqrt, rem, and round.</param>
        /// <param name="loadPreDefinedOperators">This will load %, *, :, /, +, -, >, &lt;, and =</param>
        /// <param name="loadPreDefinedVariables">This will load pi, tao, e, phi, major, minor, pitograd, and piofgrad.</param>
        /// <param name="cultureInfo">The culture info to use when parsing. If null, defaults to invariant culture.</param>
        public MathParserRevised(bool loadPreDefinedFunctions = true, bool loadPreDefinedOperators = true, bool loadPreDefinedVariables = true, CultureInfo cultureInfo = null)
        {
            if (loadPreDefinedOperators)
            {
                Operators = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, string>>(7)
                {
                    ["^"] = (a, b) => "Power(" + a + "," + b + ")",
                    ["%"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "%" + b + ")",
                    [":"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "/" + b + ")",
                    ["/"] = (a, b) => "(Divide(" + a + "," + b + "))",
                    ["*"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "*" + b + ")",
                    ["-"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "-" + b + ")",
                    ["+"] = (a, b) => "(" + a + "+" + b + ")",
                };
            }
            else
                Operators = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, string>>();

            if (loadPreDefinedFunctions)
            {
                LocalFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string[], string>>(4)
                {
                    ["Min"] = inputs => "Least(" + String.Join(", ", inputs) + ")",
                    ["Max"] = inputs => "Greatest(" + String.Join(", ", inputs) + ")",
                    ["Ztn"] = inputs => "Ztn(" + String.Join(", ", inputs) + ")",
                    ["Nvl"] = inputs => "Nvl(" + String.Join(", ", inputs) + ")"
                };
            }
            else
                LocalFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string[], string>>();


            if (loadPreDefinedVariables)
            {
                LocalVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>(8)
                {
                    ["pi"] = Math.PI.ToString(),
                    ["tao"] = "6.28318530717959",
                    ["e"] = Math.E.ToString(),
                    ["phi"] = "1.61803398874989",
                    ["major"] = "0.61803398874989",
                    ["minor"] = "0.38196601125011",

                    ["pitograd"] = "57.2957795130823",
                    ["piofgrad"] = "0.01745329251994"
                };
            }
            else
                LocalVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>();


            CultureInfo = cultureInfo ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enter the math expression in form of a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mathExpression">The math expression to parse.</param>
        /// <returns>The result of executing <paramref name="mathExpression"/>.</returns>
        public string Parse(string mathExpression)
        {
            return MathParserLogic(Lexer(mathExpression));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enter the math expression in form of a list of tokens.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mathExpression">The math expression to parse.</param>
        /// <returns>The result of executing <paramref name="mathExpression"/>.</returns>
        public string Parse(ReadOnlyCollection<string> mathExpression)
        {
            return MathParserLogic(new List<string>(mathExpression));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enter the math expression in form of a string. You might also add/edit variables using "let" keyword.
        /// For example, "let sampleVariable = 2+2".
        /// 
        /// Another way of adding/editing a variable is to type "varName := 20"
        /// 
        /// Last way of adding/editing a variable is to type "let varName be 20"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mathExpression">The math expression to parse.</param>
        /// <param name="correctExpression">If true, correct <paramref name="correctExpression"/> of any typos.</param>
        /// <param name="identifyComments">If true, treat "#", "#{", and "}#" as comments.</param>
        /// <returns>The result of executing <paramref name="mathExpression"/>.</returns>
        public string ProgrammaticallyParse(string mathExpression, bool correctExpression = true, bool identifyComments = true)
        {
            if (identifyComments)
            {
                // Delete Comments #{Comment}#
                mathExpression = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(mathExpression, "#\\{.*?\\}#", "");

                // Delete Comments #Comment
                mathExpression = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(mathExpression, "#.*$", "");
            }

            if (correctExpression)
            {
                // this refers to the Correction function which will correct stuff like artn to arctan, etc.
                mathExpression = Correction(mathExpression);
            }

            string varName;
            string varValue;

            if (mathExpression.Contains("let"))
            {
                if (mathExpression.Contains("be"))
                {
                    varName = mathExpression.Substring(mathExpression.IndexOf("let", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3,
                        mathExpression.IndexOf("be", StringComparison.Ordinal) -
                        mathExpression.IndexOf("let", StringComparison.Ordinal) - 3);
                    mathExpression = mathExpression.Replace(varName + "be", "");
                }
                else
                {
                    varName = mathExpression.Substring(mathExpression.IndexOf("let", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 3,
                        mathExpression.IndexOf("=", StringComparison.Ordinal) -
                        mathExpression.IndexOf("let", StringComparison.Ordinal) - 3);
                    mathExpression = mathExpression.Replace(varName + "=", "");
                }

                varName = varName.Replace(" ", "");
                mathExpression = mathExpression.Replace("let", "");

                varValue = Parse(mathExpression);

                if (LocalVariables.ContainsKey(varName))
                    LocalVariables[varName] = varValue;
                else
                    LocalVariables.Add(varName, varValue);

                return varValue;
            }

            if (!mathExpression.Contains(":="))
                return Parse(mathExpression);

            //mathExpression = mathExpression.Replace(" ", ""); // remove white space
            varName = mathExpression.Substring(0, mathExpression.IndexOf(":=", StringComparison.Ordinal));
            mathExpression = mathExpression.Replace(varName + ":=", "");

            varValue = Parse(mathExpression);
            varName = varName.Replace(" ", "");

            if (LocalVariables.ContainsKey(varName))
                LocalVariables[varName] = varValue;
            else
                LocalVariables.Add(varName, varValue);

            return varValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will convert a string expression into a list of tokens that can be later executed by Parse or ProgrammaticallyParse methods.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mathExpression">The math expression to tokenize.</param>
        /// <returns>The resulting tokens of <paramref name="mathExpression"/>.</returns>
        public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetTokens(string mathExpression)
        {
            return Lexer(mathExpression).AsReadOnly();
        }

        #region Core

        /// <summary>
        /// This will correct sqrt() and arctan() written in different ways only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string Correction(string input)
        {
            // Word corrections

            input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "\\b(sqr|sqrt)\\b", "sqrt",
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "\\b(atan2|arctan2)\\b", "arctan2",
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            //... and more

            return input;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tokenizes <paramref name="expr"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expr">The expression to tokenize.</param>
        /// <returns>The tokens.</returns>
        private List<string> Lexer(string expr)
        {
            var token = "";
            var tokens = new List<string>();

            expr = expr.Replace("+-", "-");
            expr = expr.Replace("-+", "-");
            expr = expr.Replace("--", "+");

            for (var i = 0; i < expr.Length; i++)
            {
                var ch = expr[i];

                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(ch))
                    continue;

                if (char.IsLetter(ch))
                {
                    if (i != 0 && (char.IsDigit(expr[i - 1]) || expr[i - 1] == ')'))
                        tokens.Add("*");

                    token += ch;

                    while (i + 1 < expr.Length && char.IsLetterOrDigit(expr[i + 1]))
                        token += expr[++i];

                    tokens.Add(token);
                    token = "";

                    continue;
                }

                if (char.IsDigit(ch))
                {
                    token += ch;

                    while (i + 1 < expr.Length && (char.IsDigit(expr[i + 1]) || expr[i + 1] == '.'))
                        token += expr[++i];

                    tokens.Add(token);
                    token = "";

                    continue;
                }

                if(ch == '.')
                {
                    token += ch;

                    while (i + 1 < expr.Length && char.IsDigit(expr[i + 1]))
                        token += expr[++i];

                    tokens.Add(token);
                    token = "";

                    continue;
                }

                if (i + 1 < expr.Length && (ch == '-' || ch == '+') && char.IsDigit(expr[i + 1]) &&
                    (i == 0 || Operators.ContainsKey(expr[i - 1].ToString(
#if !NETSTANDARD1_4 
                        CultureInfo 
#endif
                        )) ||
                     i - 1 > 0 && expr[i - 1] == '('))
                {
                    // if the above is true, then the token for that negative number will be "-1", not "-","1".
                    // to sum up, the above will be true if the minus sign is in front of the number, but
                    // at the beginning, for example, -1+2, or, when it is inside the brakets (-1).
                    // NOTE: this works for + as well!

                    token += ch;

                    while (i + 1 < expr.Length && (char.IsDigit(expr[i + 1]) || expr[i + 1] == '.'))
                        token += expr[++i];

                    tokens.Add(token);
                    token = "";

                    continue;
                }

                if (ch == '(')
                {
                    if (i != 0 && (char.IsDigit(expr[i - 1]) || char.IsDigit(expr[i - 1]) || expr[i - 1] == ')'))
                    {
                        tokens.Add("*");
                        tokens.Add("(");
                    }
                    else
                        tokens.Add("(");
                }
                else
                    tokens.Add(ch.ToString());
            }

            return tokens;
        }

        private string MathParserLogic(List<string> tokens)
        {
            // Variables replacement
            for (var i = 0; i < tokens.Count; i++)
            {
                if (LocalVariables.Keys.Contains(tokens[i]))
                    tokens[i] = LocalVariables[tokens[i]];
            }

            while (tokens.IndexOf("(") != -1)
            {
                // getting data between "(" and ")"
                var open = tokens.LastIndexOf("(");
                var close = tokens.IndexOf(")", open); // in case open is -1, i.e. no "(" // , open == 0 ? 0 : open - 1

                if (open >= close)
                    throw new ArithmeticException("No closing bracket/parenthesis. Token: " + open.ToString(CultureInfo));

                var roughExpr = new List<string>();

                for (var i = open + 1; i < close; i++)
                    roughExpr.Add(tokens[i]);

                string tmpResult;

                var args = new List<string>();
                var functionName = tokens[open == 0 ? 0 : open - 1];

                if (LocalFunctions.Keys.Contains(functionName))
                {
                    if (roughExpr.Contains(","))
                    {
                        // converting all arguments into a decimal array
                        for (var i = 0; i < roughExpr.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var defaultExpr = new List<string>();
                            var firstCommaOrEndOfExpression =
                                roughExpr.IndexOf(",", i) != -1
                                    ? roughExpr.IndexOf(",", i)
                                    : roughExpr.Count;

                            while (i < firstCommaOrEndOfExpression)
                                defaultExpr.Add(roughExpr[i++]);

                            args.Add(defaultExpr.Count == 0 ? "0" : BasicArithmeticalExpression(defaultExpr));
                        }

                        // finally, passing the arguments to the given function
                        tmpResult = LocalFunctions[functionName](args.ToArray());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // but if we only have one argument, then we pass it directly to the function
                        tmpResult = LocalFunctions[functionName](new[]
                        {
                            BasicArithmeticalExpression(roughExpr)
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // if no function is need to execute following expression, pass it
                    // to the "BasicArithmeticalExpression" method.
                    tmpResult = BasicArithmeticalExpression(roughExpr);
                }

                // when all the calculations have been done
                // we replace the "opening bracket with the result"
                // and removing the rest.
                tokens[open] = tmpResult;
                tokens.RemoveRange(open + 1, close - open);

                if (LocalFunctions.Keys.Contains(functionName))
                {
                    // if we also executed a function, removing
                    // the function name as well.
                    tokens.RemoveAt(open - 1);
                }
            }

            // at this point, we should have replaced all brackets
            // with the appropriate values, so we can simply
            // calculate the expression. it's not so complex
            // any more!
            return BasicArithmeticalExpression(tokens);
        }

        private string BasicArithmeticalExpression(List<string> tokens)
        {
            // PERFORMING A BASIC ARITHMETICAL EXPRESSION CALCULATION
            // THIS METHOD CAN ONLY OPERATE WITH NUMBERS AND OPERATORS
            // AND WILL NOT UNDERSTAND ANYTHING BEYOND THAT.

            switch (tokens.Count)
            {
                case 1:
                    return tokens[0];
                case 2:
                    var op = tokens[0];

                    if (op == "-" || op == "+")
                    {
                        var first = op == "+" ? "" : (tokens[1].Substring(0, 1) == "-" ? "" : "-");

                        return first + tokens[1];
                    }

                    return Operators[op]("0", tokens[1]);
                case 0:
                    return "0";
            }

            foreach (var op in Operators)
            {
                int opPlace;

                while ((opPlace = tokens.IndexOf(op.Key)) != -1)
                {
                    var numberA = tokens[opPlace - 1];
                    var numberB = tokens[opPlace + 1];

                    var result = op.Value(numberA, numberB);

                    tokens[opPlace - 1] = result;
                    tokens.RemoveRange(opPlace, 2);
                }
            }

            return tokens[0];
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```